# JQuery / Ajax / formSubmit / preventDefault Issue with Safari on iPad

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, ipad, safari

We do have a site the works fine in all tested environments. But we are facing a problem on Safari (only) on iPads. Chrome on iPad works like it should do ...

We do have a form, that is submitted via ajax and brings some results. Only in Safari, the form is "really submitted" - the preventDefault is totally ignored by Safari.

```
<form id="adr_search">
  <input type="text" name="adr" id="adr" style="width: 90px;" value="" class="search_field"/> 
  <input type="submit" value="go!" />
</form>


$(function() 
{
    $("#adr_search").submit(function(event) 
    {
        event.preventDefault;
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
          headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
          type: 'POST',
            url: './../code/process/ajax_geo_find_adr.php',
            data: data,
            success: function(res){
                var res = $.parseJSON(res);
                alert(res.address);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

There are a lot of questions and answers around this topic, but i have not been able to find a solution, that works in our scenario.